# Why is tkinter not displaying anything?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.11

Im trying out tkinter to make a UI game but it  is not displaying anything in the window that opens, there is no error in the shell.

```
import tkinter as tk

count = 0

def on_button_click():
    global count
    count += 1
    label.config(text="You have clicked " + str(clicks) + " times!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Game")
root.geometry("800x600")

root.mainloop()

# button
button = tk.Button(root, text ="Click me", command=on_button_click)
button.pack()

# label
label = tk.Label(root, text="Jitter click the button")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[The output of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PFd7.png)

i have tried searching up different tutorials on tkinter but they all act the same, is it something obvious I'm missing

Comment: You seem to have `root.mainloop()` twice. I would delete the one in the middle and keep the one at the end.

Comment: The `root.mainloop()` will do the entire script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your label & button creation code is outside your root.mainloop() and you have the mainloop() line twice.